# SQL - Reverse Part of Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to reverse part of column. Ex;

```
    SELECT Column FROM Table ORDER BY Column ASC
```

Output:

```
Column
------
Kaan001
Kaan002
Kaan003
Turan001
Turan002
```

If I use DESC instead of ASC;

```
Column
------
Turan002
Turan001
Kaan003
Kaan002
Kaan001
```

But I want this;

```
Column
------
Turan001
Turan002
Kaan001
Kaan002
Kaan003
```

Is it possible or not? Please Help me... Thank you..

Comment: what is the rule ?

Comment: So you want the string to be in descending order and numerals part to be in ascending ordered? I think you will need to write a procedure that splits the strings, groups them based on the string and then sorts them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
order by left(columnname, len(columnname) - 3) desc,
         right(columnname, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are required to use `DESC`. It will return the result by the mentioned column in the descending order.

```
SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName ORDER BY ColumnName DESC
```

If you are *not* explicitly mentioned the Column's ORDER BY it will consider as `ASC` (ascending order) by default.

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b1c902899ce098b59aa075e9cce78ce)

---

As per your edited question, the following query will work using `PATINDEX`

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY LEFT(ColumnName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ColumnName) - 1) DESC, 
         RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ColumnName) + 1) ASC
```

[**Updated db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eac1accba786cd24e1ce6d4073ea3a0d)

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN I have updated my answer, please check the query and the demo. It is working with out hard-coding the numeric size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
create table #temp (
    id int identity(1,1),
    testCol Varchar(20)
)

insert into #temp values ('Turan002'),('Turan001'),('Kaan003'),('Kaan002'),('Kaan001')    

SELECT 
    * from 
    #temp order by RTRIM(SUBSTRING( testCol , 1 , CHARINDEX( '0' , testCol) - 1)) desc, 
       RTRIM(SUBSTRING( testCol , CHARINDEX( '0' , testCol ), LEN( testCol) - (CHARINDEX( '0' , testCol) - 1))) asc

drop table #temp
```

You can find the demo [Here](https://rextester.com/UANH71032).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,

```
select * from (
 values 
 ('Kaan001')
,('Kaan002')
,('Kaan003')
,('Turan001')
,('Turan002')
) d (val) 
order by left (val, PATINDEX ('%[0-9]%', val) - 1) desc
, right (val, PATINDEX ('%[0-9]%', val)) -- Here, Patindex returns the first appearance of integer.
```